Microsoft Entra authentication with Blazor server
I have created a blazor server application and I am using MicrosoftIdentity to authenticate the user.
When I have serverprerender in _Host.cshtml it works perfectly. But does not work when I make it just server.
// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp()
    .EnableTokenAcquisitionToCallDownstreamApi(initialScopes)
    .AddMicrosoftGraph(builder.Configuration.GetSection("DownstreamApi"))
    .AddInMemoryTokenCaches(); // apis


If the user is not logged in the app redirects the browser to this address
https://localhost:7106/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn
which again redirects to Microsoft login page.
But when I set rendering mode from "serverprerenderd" to "server"
https://localhost:7106/MicrosoftIdentity/Account/SignIn this does not forward the browser to MS login page and just displays that there is not content in this page.
